# Is Spring Boot Bundling a Login Page By Default?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I haven't done any UI setup at all, but when I go to localhost:8080 on a spring boot 2.1.3 app that I start up, I get redirected to localhost:8080/login. Is there something being bundled with spring boot on the frontend, and how do I get rid of it? I want to put my own frontend app in. Right now I am just testing API calls, but later I will want to put in my own frontend part.

Comment: You must have spring-security jars on your classpath. As a result spring-boot enales basic security by default. Pls refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636368/how-to-disable-spring-security-login-screen

Answer (score 1):

The redirect to a login page is part of `spring-security`.

You can either remove the dependency to spring-security in your maven or gradle setup or disable the login redirection:

- [How can I disable spring form based login for RESTful endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946903/how-can-i-disable-spring-form-based-login-for-restful-endpoints)
- [How to disable spring-security login screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636368/how-to-disable-spring-security-login-screen)
- [Spring security without form login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985709/spring-security-without-form-login)